# Short story about mankind preparing for contact with an approaching alien spacecraft, finally passing by and ignoring humans

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, aliens

Looking for a short story that I read in the 1980s.  Following the discovery of an alien spacecraft apparently bound to Earth, plagued with conflicts, mankind organizes and prepares for contact, setting up a complete protocol.
This preparation turns out to be in vain, as the alien spacecraft just passes by and leaves, completely ignoring Earth and humans.

Important: this is the core plot of this short story (not a novel). Clarke's *Rendezvous with Rama* and *Fountains of Paradise* are not the answer, as these are novels and their core plots are much larger than that.

Comment: Could this be "The Ethical Equations" by Murray Leinster?

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunately, this is not the one. I could find it on the net and the story is much different.

Answer (score 4):

"The Invasion of Venus" by Stephen Baxter could be a match. The alien spacecraft does indeed ignore Earth and humans completely. But it doesn't simply "pass by and leave"; it wreaks a bit of havoc elsewhere in the solar system before departing.

Comment: Thank you, but this is not the one. No "havoc" part, and the short story I have in mind is pre-1990s (I read it in the 1980s). This one is from 2010.